# Building a 60x36 Barn/Tractor Garage/Shop - Question about Structural Integrity

Tags: wood, garage, construction, barn

New here! I am a DIYer and I'm looking to build a shed/garage on my property. I designed the structure but am wanting to see if anyone can give me input on the integrity of my design. Basically I just want to make sure my roof wont fall in and my walls can take a decent wind load as I am in tornado country.

The pictures attached show a 60x36 structure. 48x36 is garage and 12x24 is closed in shop. It's a single slope roof that starts at 14' at the front and goes to 8' at the back. Posts will be placed into the ground 4' minimum.

I am using 6x6's for the posts and sistered 2x12x12's for the beams that span 12'. I also added some 6x6 bracing along the outside walls to help. I plan on having a plywood roof with galvalume metal on top. Haven't decided on siding but I'm leaning towards a shiplap type siding.

But back to my original question, will this be structurally safe and sound. Is it overkill or do I need to add to it? Thank you in advance for your input!

Answer (score 2):

If you want actual structural advice, hire an engineer licensed to practice in your location.

For plans that are **already engineered for your location**, particularly for "agricultural buildings" you might want to consult with your local agricultural extension website, where you might find several hundred choices.

The plans are commonly free (you already paid for them with your taxes) or very inexpensive. They are very likely to include details you have not thought of, and not to waste extra material where it does little or no good (a common failing of amateur building designers, often combined with failing to apply 10 cents worth of material where it will do five dollars worth of good.)

*(note - I play amateur building designer, but I also read Dad's civil engineering books for fun, and have a pretty good idea when I should call in the pros, as well as a better than average knowledge of when & where to apply that 10 cents worth of material due to my reading.)*

Comment: I agree, 2000sf structures are not the kind of thing you get to "freestyle" off the cuff.  You need engineer approval.  Even if you're in rural Texas and "there is no zoning/inspection", *that you know of*... your chickens WILL come home to roost when insurance, accident investigation or property sale comes into the picture. Freedom doesn't mean freedom from consequences.